# Trouble using cucumber/capybara/selenium with different browsers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, selenium-webdriver, cucumber, capybara

I setup my env.rb the way [this guy](https://100000linesofcode.wordpress.com/2014/04/28/cucumbercapybara-testing-using-firefox-chrome-safari-opera-poltergeistphantomjs-and-it-works/) recommended is set up. I started my app locally and when I run 
firefox=true bundle exec cucumber features/01_login.feature
I get the following

> cannot load such file -- capybara/poltergeist (LoadError)
>   /Users/gabrielpumple/bi/features/support/env.rb:3:in `require'
>   /Users/gabrielpumple/bi/features/support/env.rb:3:in`'
>   /Users/gabrielpumple/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/cucumber-1.3.10/lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:122:in
>   `load'
>   /Users/gabrielpumple/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/cucumber-1.3.10/lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:122:in`
>   load_code_file'
>   /Users/gabrielpumple/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/cucumber-1.3.10/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:180:in `load_file'
>   /Users/gabrielpumple/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/cucumber-1.3.10/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:83:in`
>   block in load_files!'
>   /Users/gabrielpumple/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/cucumber-1.3.10/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:82:in
>   `each'
>   /Users/gabrielpumple/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/cucumber-1.3.10/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:82:in`
>   load_files!'
>   /Users/gabrielpumple/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/cucumber-1.3.10/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:184:in
>   `load_step_definitions'
>   /Users/gabrielpumple/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/cucumber-1.3.10/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:42:in`
>   run!'
>   /Users/gabrielpumple/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/cucumber-1.3.10/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:47:in
>   `execute!'
>   /Users/gabrielpumple/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/gems/cucumber-1.3.10/bin/cucumber:13:in`
>   '
>   /Users/gabrielpumple/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/bin/cucumber:23:in
>   `load'
>   /Users/gabrielpumple/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/bin/cucumber:23:in`
>   '
>   /Users/gabrielpumple/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in
>   `eval'
>   /Users/gabrielpumple/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in`
>   '

I have already installed poltergeist/phantomjs and run bundle install. My colleagues and I have the tests working properly in chrome, but we need to run them with different browsers. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I got some help from a coworker and now the tests are running in firefox, and hopefully soon on ie. Here is how he changed the env.rb file

```
require 'cucumber/rails'
Capybara.default_selector = :css
cb = ENV['CURRENT_BROWSER']
testbrowser = cb ? cb.downcase.to_sym : :firefox
puts "-------------- current browser: #{testbrowser}........."
Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
  if RbConfig::CONFIG['host_os'][/linux/] && testbrowser.to_s.eql?("CHROME".downcase)
    Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, {:browser => :remote, :url => "http://127.0.0.1:9515"})
  else
    if testbrowser.eql?(:chrome)
      Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :chrome, :switches => %w[--test-type])
    elsif testbrowser.eql?(:safari)
       Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :safari, :switches => %w[--test-type])
    elsif testbrowser.eql?(:internetexplorer)
      Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :internetexplorer, :switches => %w[--test-type])
    else
      Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => testbrowser)
    end
  end
end

ActionController::Base.allow_rescue = false

begin
  DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
rescue NameError
  raise "You need to add database_cleaner to your Gemfile (in the :test group) if you wish to use it."
end

Cucumber::Rails::Database.javascript_strategy = :truncation
```

Then when I run a feature from the command line I use

```
bundle exec cucumber CURRENT_BROWSER=chrome feature/myFeature.feature
```

for Chrome, or

```
bundle exec cucumber feature/myFeature.feature
```

for Firefox (default). The opera driver still didn't want to work for me, and only 1% of people use it so I'm not worried, and Safari driver doesn't support modal interaction so if your test involves a validation window or interacting with a deliberate failure say on login, safari won't work. I kept the Safari option in case they update the Safari driver, or if I have a very simple test I'd like to be able to run. I will update after I have seen if it works properly on IE.